# OnClickListener gets triggered when button in another place

Tags: android, onclicklistener, imagebutton

I have four `ImageButton`s in my app.

[image]

Three smaller buttons can be either shown or "hidden" below the bigger button. I hide buttons using rotate and translate animations.

**The problem is:** 
`OnClickListener`'s `onClick` method always gets triggered no matter a smaller button shown or not.

I mean, when smaller buttons are "hidden", touching the place on screen, where one of the smaller button resides when shown, triggers `onClick` method.

It looks like Android OS does not take actual placement of the button into account when deciding whether it should trigger `onClick` method or not.

How can I overcome the issue?

I want `onClick` method to be called ONLY when there is a button below my finger.

**EDIT:**

All suggested workarounds rely on hiding the button. This doesn't help at all. The `onClick` method gets called for `INVISIBLE` and `GONE` buttons too. I checked this in debugger.

Comment: Might be problem of reference .. Your button might be not getting proper reference at time of click.

Comment: put a condition in onClick `if(view.isShown()){// perform opertaions}`

Comment: @AndroidHacker I am not sure what are you talking about. Would you care to elaborate on that?

Comment: @Sunny this won't help because the button is shown (just moved below other button).

Comment: i.e Might be you are not getting view on click. I can more specific on this if you manage to post code over here

Comment: i.e Might be you are not getting view on click. I can be more specific on this if you manage to post code over here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the fact that tween animations (the original animation framework)  animate the pixels, not the touch zones of a widget.

I have replaced tween animations with [property animations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) and now everything works like I expect it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are going for an Arc menu. Why not use the awesome implementations of [Siyamed](https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu) and [DaCapricorn](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu), instead of re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: Thank you for the links. Projects look great and I might be using them in one of my other applications.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set your click interface your activity and implemented onClickListener? If so you need to separated your buttons by setting if conditions like if(arg0 == button1) for all the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest setting the button visibility to GONE after completing the animation.

UPDATE:

Another suggestion is to have a button that is not animated (for which the problem should not happen) and an image (graphically identical) that is animated after the button is hidden. The image should not receive any clicks, under the big button or not, and the real button should not receive clicks when hidden.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't helped. The button is hidden but onClick gets called.

Comment: Are you sure that the thing that responds to the clicks is the button? I can imagine transparent click areas above buttons, parent views taking care about all clicks and redirecting the calls, etc. What is the view passed to onClick? And what in the stack trace printed by _new Exception().printStackTrace()_?

Comment: in `onClick` handler the view is image button, the `v.isShown() == false` and `v.getVisibility == 4` (or 8)

Comment: Then just ignore clicks coming from buttons whose `v.isShown() == false`

Comment: or, set its "clickable" to false.

Comment: One more suggestion is to clean and rebuild :) -- just in case you didn't do this

Answer (score 0):

Setting

```
btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

doesn't call onClick method where buttons are not visible. I have tested it. So you might be registering onClick listener in unnecessary views.

Comment: I checked and I get onClick called for hidden buttons.

Comment: Now it is almost impossible to answer without code? Just show some relevant part of the code

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the listener using the property onClick of the button in the layout.xml (for example

```
android:onClick="onClickButtonCamera"
```

and then declare a public function with the same name like:

```
public void onClickButtonCamera(View view) {
    //some stuff...
}
```

I allways use it and the function is never called when the buttons are hidden.
I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

i think there are three ways to solve this issue.

1)  if you are setting onClick Listener then set it null when you hide buttons and set listener   when you show them.

2)Add a checking in onclick for each button about their visibility simply return; the function when button's visibility is not VISIBLE(use the function button.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)

3)Last one not sure, usually setting gone as visibility will protect it from clicking.